# Storing real time canvas session data on Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket, html5-canvas

Im writing a real time paint application using nodeJS + HTML5 canvas & websockets

currently server just acts as an relay and what ever each user draws is broadcast to the rest of the users.

The problem here is that when new users show up they start with a empty canvas.

I have two ideas on how to solve this,

1) the event driven approach - this is where i persist in memory each and every draw event. and when the new user shows up to the session. All events are reconstructed and sent to him/her.

2) the server maintains a copy of the canvas. So rather than just relaying the draw events, the server also renders all the draw events. When new user shows up, this state is then passed on to it.

Anyone has any thoughts on the pros and cons of the both approach or better yet, a better way to solve it!

Comment: Ran into this issue myself while doing my thesis. I used the second option and used redis to store canvas data and when a user joins send the data accross the socket. This way every new connection has all the data on the screen

Comment: @Dennington-bear wow glad to know im not alone. Thanks! did it have any impact on your speed of delivery to users? as compared to just relaying? Thought of using redis too!

Comment: I only tested it on my colleges local net. But I had around 100 clients running with no visible lag off the host. Around the 120-130 mark is when I noticed lag. But even then I for some reason went down the route of using child process with node.js which was not the best direction to go. Now if I was doing it I would look more towards clusters. I feel this would give you a lot more performance as I probably left costly bugs everywhere that hampered performance. Redis was easily the best available option for me but for your use case this could be different.

Comment: I sent three.js objects using socket.io and stored them in redis from the host and then pipped it out to the clients. But depending on the data you send there may be other issues you should look into. My case was more game object intensive so just pure data no images or anything else

Comment: @Dennington-bear thanks for the info. Is your redis project opensource? haha some source code would really help me! anyways submit an answer and ill make this as answered:)

Comment: Go onto my profile and email me ill send you on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my opinionated answer.
The best approach is to have the server maintain a copy of the of the data via a db. This means that whenever your client starts they will always have data to use in the case of dropped packets upon new client starting and also being able to maintain legacy data. When I developed a similar concept I used game objects as an example and got a good return to many clients. Without noticeable lag on a local net even with a faulty design concept. Hope this helps